# what's the difference between CameraCilent and Camera2Client in android?

Tags: android, camera

In android JB 4.2, there is the Class which is Camera2Cilent in the av/services/camera/libcameraservice/ . I have no idea about the Camera2.

Does anyone know the Camera2 in the android ? What's the difference between the CameraCilent and Camera2Client.

I had googled ,but there is very little information about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 4.2 introduced a new Camera Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL), *Camera 2.0*. Camera2Client is the ICamera implementation that actually runs on top of this new HAL.

In theory, the new HAL focuses on collection and providing metadata associated with each frame. It also provides the ability to re-process streams. In practise, I don't think the Android SDK exposes any of the new functionality. It's more of an architectural improvement, getting things future-proof. I could be wrong there.